# Type safe equal tuple sizes.

Tags: haskell

How can I write best write a type signature in Haskell that best encapsulates the idea that a function must be passed a tuple of any length with all elements X, and a list of tuples (of the same length) with all elements Y?

I don't mind if the type passed is a "real" tuple some alternate data type, as long as I can enforce at compile time that both the tuple and the list of tuples have the same length.

```
Tuple N X -> [Tuple N Y] -> Z
```

Comment: Long shot but could you use DataKinds to create your own 'length-indexed vectors' and then use those to constrain your function parameters? https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/promotion.html

Comment: Or use this: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-list-0.1.6/docs/Data-FixedList.html

Comment: I suspect neither of the two above are general enough :(

Comment: @zoran119, I see nothing wrong with using length-indexed vectors.

Comment: This is not really an answer, but here's a nice article describing something along similar lines: https://blog.jle.im/entry/practical-dependent-types-in-haskell-1.html

Comment: Another option to consider is to accept a list of tuples instead. It conveys the idea that you need as many Xs as Ys and it's probably the simplest to deal with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As zoran119 suggests, length-indexed vectors are the classic way to do this.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat

data Vec n a where
  Nil :: Vec 'Z a
  Cons :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec ('S n) a
```

Now you can easily write

```
f :: Vec n X -> [Vec n Y] -> Z
```